# Владимир и Вольдемар

Tags: имена-собственные

Мне попадалась информация, что русское имя Владимир происходит от варяжского (какого-то из скандинавских, сейчас конкретно не припомню) Вольдемар. И в 19 веке в дворянской среде Владимиров по моде того времени тоже переделывали на западный манер в Вольдемаров.
Но мне бы хотелось знать, действительно ли Владимир - это переделанное на русский лад скандинавское имя, или это измышления, Владимир - чисто русское имя, просто созвучное иностранному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не похожа эта переделка на скандинавскую. Длинновато, да и по фонетике не проходит.
Более на французский манер тянет. Что, кстати, и подтверждается салонным использованием в XIX веке - на пике моды на французский язык.

Касательно самого имени Владимир. Совершенно очевидны славянские корни. Владимhръ - вполне обычное для того времени образование, мhръ - морф, со значением "наделенный", "обдадающий". 
Зализняк где-то приводил несколько подобным образом построенных имен, более того - не только княжеских. Искать ссылки пока не буду, но если очень потребуется, найду.
Значение таким образом - "владетельный".

Comment: Яромир, Любомир, Тихомир, Радомир, город Житомир...  
Не знал, что "мир" в данном случае - "наделённый".

Comment: Это общая ошибка, почти все неспециалисты трактуют как "владеть миром". Но там исходно ять, т.е. "мер", однокоренное, если не ошибаюсь с "мерить", "отмеривать" Никак не "мир" (мiр).
Именно по этой причине Грот настаивал на написании Вдадимиръ через обычное И, в то время как однокоренные с "мир" (вселенная) требовали I десятеричного: мipъ.   
  
Что касается ваших примеров, то навскидку наверняка не скажу, где в них "мир", где "мhp". Тут надо смотреть время образования. Морф "мhр" потерял продуктивность в собственных именах очень давно. Но похоже, Ваши примеры именно на "мhръ".

Comment: Во всех примерах "наделённый" подходит куда лучше, чем "общество", "планета" или "окружающее".

Answer (score 3):

Русское (славянское) имя Владимир первично. Вольдемар/Вальдемар - переделанное на скандинавский лад княжеское имя.

> Датский язык сохранил и зримые следы тех тесных связей, которые существовали когда-то между Данией викингов и Древней Русью. О том, насколько эти связи были реальными и тесными, судите сами: Вальдемар I Великий, чье правление — с 1157-го по 1182.г. — вошло в историю Дании как «блестящее», был внуком русского князя Мстислава, более того, он и родился в России, и само его имя Вальдемар — это на самом деле переделанное русское «Владимир». Благодаря этому датский язык пополнился целым рядом чисто русских слов. Так, «купить» в датском языке стало «кёбе», «плуг» превратился в датский «плов», «столб» произносится как «столпе», «толмач» превратился в датский «толю», то есть «переводчик», а слово «торг», обозначавшее в древнерусском людное место, где происходит торговля, стал датским «торв», которое переводится и как «торговая площадь», и как «ярмарка » и присутствует в названиях многих улиц и площадей датских городов. Как это ни смешно, датчане позаимствовали у нас и наши ругательства — их «дрог» и есть наш «дурак». Со времен Вальдемара Великого их пограничники охраняют «грэнсе» — «граница». Русская «сабля» стала датской «сабел», а покрывающий коня «чепрак» — «щаберак». «Чижик» по-датски стал «сискен». Ну а в наше время датчане больше всего любят заимствовать из русского женские имена. «Нина», «Надя», «Даша» давно вошли в датский обиход. Бесспорным же лидером по популярности является, конечно, «Катя». В 2004 году, например, Катей стала каждая пятая из родившихся тогда девочек.

http://denmark.geography.kz/datskij-yazyk.html

Данное мнение (Владимир => Вальдемар) может быть оспорено, скорее всего, только одним способом - предоставлением информации о любом скандинавском правителе по имени Вальдемар, правившем ДО первого русского князя, носившего имя Владимир (Владимир Святой, 980-1015).

Comment: В датском языке вообще нет слов, начинающихся с VL, WL. Так что данное звукосочетание в начале имени собственного автоматом влечет искажение в произношении. Датчане не могут произнести Владимир, Володимир - могут. Но смысла не видят в корне, поэтому им ближе собственный корень подставить, например созвучное wild-дикий. DEMAR--созвучен их понятию границы.

Comment: Вам могут возразить, что там "ФЛ", должно быть, как во всех  германских. Оно соответствует славянскому "ВЛ" или "ХВЛ"...   
Где вы  видели в скандинавских ударение на последнем слоге? Это начисто убивает всю идею.

Comment: Да не пишется и не читается в датском FL вместо VL, там нет вокальной замены V-F как в немецком и нидерландском, где  VOLKS читается как Фолкc.  В противном случае обратная транскрипция была бы через f Foldemar.
У них есть один корешок  Flad- со значением плоский, дак и то похоже заимствовано с заменой произношения, от того же русского через хлад, глад с исходным русским лед. и тем самым смысловым-плоский.
А там и так ударение на второе а, Демаркация, с русским корнем марка, от марать-пачкать, смарать-стирать, производные насморк, сморкать, насмарку.